# C# + Google Storage signed URL: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I just created this bucket: `mybucket231`.

Running this C# code to generate Signed-Url:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"path/to/secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var cred = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                               .CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control")
                               .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;

    var urlSigner = UrlSigner.FromServiceAccountCredential(cred);
    var publicLink = urlSigner.Sign("mybucket231", "file.test", TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
}
```

This code generate Signed URL with `full_control` permission. Getting back url looks like this:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket231/file.test?GoogleAccessId=new-storage-service-account@dotnet-core-cluster.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1548606014&Signature=HbL0ETXucaldz8jpoUDXUzYQu2YyhiMUh4Nfm69Y0sLyG3pvqbVvMMK1N8agywE8gW8s7kkInJCJuVGH%2FAHzd4LfeYo62iFK....FjnImQZq7fftv4TF5SpCPsVFnOGkSD6vOIpKqfJiswqGIERC9D7EJ%2B2DZ9JVMP7cEYjmAB9miemtD2eTVXu3FpBNbnDoxp112eTmu2F4TAckS0toX%2FmYk8GhOc9UnWH1iZ5VJ%2FKslFmRU0NFu4nxkDv7rk%2FRCvsOvvqrOqJT6cezE%2Bz%2FMONh%2FK5KfPs0ZnYslQwYNojhVR4sn5L8tVNst6gclFnA%3D%3D
```

Now, I'm going to Fiddler and tring to create file with this command:

```
PUT https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket231/file.test?GoogleAccessId=new-storage-service-account@secret.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1548606014&Signature=HbL0ETXucaldz8jpoUDXUzYQu2YyhiMUh4Nfm69Y0sLyG3pvqbVvMMK1N8agywE8gW8s7kkInJCJuVGH%2FAHzd4LfeYo62iFK....FjnImQZq7fftv4TF5SpCPsVFnOGkSD6vOIpKqfJiswqGIERC9D7EJ%2B2DZ9JVMP7cEYjmAB9miemtD2eTVXu3FpBNbnDoxp112eTmu2F4TAckS0toX%2FmYk8GhOc9UnWH1iZ5VJ%2FKslFmRU0NFu4nxkDv7rk%2FRCvsOvvqrOqJT6cezE%2Bz%2FMONh%2FK5KfPs0ZnYslQwYNojhVR4sn5L8tVNst6gclFnA%3D%3D

Headers:
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: storage.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 3
content-type: text/plain

Body:
Hello world!
```

This `PUT` message gives back error 403 (Forbidden) with this message:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message><StringToSign>PUT

plain/text
1548606014
/mybucket231/file.test</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

It says: **SignatureDoesNotMatch**. But it's strange. I create this file and try the verb `GET` - *same signature does working*!

How? How to solve the `PUT` verb?

Note: My service account (`new-storage-service-account@secret.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) is StorageAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. Actully, it was two problems:

1. You must specify `content-type` header. So add
2. Then I had another problem. Allowing `content-type` in lower case - it's not enough! it should be `Content-Type` instead.

Final code:

```
string url = urlSigner.Sign(
            "mybucket231",
            "file.test",
            TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
            HttpMethod.Put,
            contentHeaders: new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> {
                    { "Content-Type", new[] { "text/plain" } }
                }
            );
```